# C# Parallel processing concept

Tags: c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I am working on image processing with C# and implementing integral histogram. I am not getting into the details, but assume that I have MxN matrix and each cell value is the sum of itself and its left and upper neighbor, minus left upper corner neighbor. This works fast but I want to make it faster for large images or for real time image processing performance.

```
matrix[i,j] += matrix[i-1,j] + matrix[i,j-1] - matrix[i-1,j-1];
```

The actual implementation is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                int left = 0, upper = 0, u_l_corner = 0;
                if (j - 1 >= 0)
                {
                    left = matrix[i, j - 1];
                }
                if (i - 1 >= 0)
                {
                    upper = matrix[i - 1, j];
                }
                if (j - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 >= 0)
                    u_l_corner = matrix[i - 1, j - 1];

                matrix[i, j] += left + upper - u_l_corner;
            }
```

So the calculation is dependent on the previous values of cells. Therefore, it does not look like it can be implemented in parallel(at least to me). But still, just want to make sure before go any further..

Can this algorithm be implemented in parallel using Parallel.For or any other method in C#? If so a simple example is highly appreciated, but if not, I better work on to find a "parallel image histogram algorithm", if any exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not 100% sure about your question (though I suspect that your current algorithm is *not* parrallellizable) but one quick optimization you could implement is to populate the first row and column of the matrix initially, and then run your current code. That will save you a bunch of unnecessary bounds checking in the inner loop. (Note: that might not actually make a difference since a) the compiler *might* already be optimizing in a similar fashion and b) if the matrix isn't that large, the speed-up (if any) would be minimal.)

Comment: @dlev: My question is if the algorithm can be parallelized or not. As I said, to me, it looks very much like an non-parallelizable algorithm. The optimization you mention is implemented in my actual program, but I did not put it here to make the algorithm clear and simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned it is possible to make this algorithm parallel but i find no use of doing so if your matrix is relatively small ( time to process is less than few miliseconds ).

If you are very interested in making this algorithm parallel you could make this task splitted to exactly "j" tasks ( number of items in "y" axis ).

Key to doing so is starting first thread to calculate points in first row of this matrice ( [i, 0] ) then starting second thread delayed - second thread should chase first thread - must never overtake preceding thread.